# Reveal JS - Controls only on speaker view

Tags: reveal.js

Is it possible to have Reveal JS only display the control arrows on the speaker view?

Setting `controls: false` disables the arrows on both the main display, and the speaker display. My presentation is in front of a live audience, so they don't need to see the controls, but it'd be handy for me to be able to see them, so I know when I've got slides "below" the current one, as well as "to the right" of it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your presentation is loaded as the main page (not in an iframe) adding the following to your presentation should work.

```
<style>
  .reveal .controls {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .notes .reveal .controls {
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>

<script>
  if (window.self !== window.top) {
    document.body.className += " notes";
  }
</script>
```

This adds a notes class to the body when the presentation is loaded within an iframe (as is done with the notes plugin). The styling then hides the controls unless it's on the speaker notes page.

If you add it before the call to `Reveal.initialize()` you shouldn't see the controls at all. Adding it after may result in the controls briefly appearing before being hidden.